# d3 color gradient linear scale not working

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, data-visualization

I have the following creating two circles for each data point, based on the latitude, longitude. The circles differ in size and color. I'd like for the "fill" in circles1 to be based on a color gradient value returned by colorScale. However, the circles just appear black. What am I getting wrong here?

```
d3.csv("cities-lived.csv", function(data) {

var colorScale = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([-15, 7.5, 30])
    .range(["#2c7bb6", "#ffff8c", "#d7191c"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateHcl);

var circles1 = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.years * 2);
    })
    .style("fill", function(d) {
        return colorScale(d.temp);
    })    
        .style("opacity", 0.85) 

.on("mouseover", function(d) {      
        div.transition()        
           .duration(200)      
           .style("opacity", .9);      
           div.text(d.place)
           .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
           .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");    
    })   

    // fade out tooltip on mouse out               
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {       
        div.transition()        
           .duration(500)      
           .style("opacity", 0);   
    })

var circles2 = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
        return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.avg * 2);
    })
        .style("fill", "none")    
        .style("opacity", 0.85) 
        .style("stroke", "black")
        .style("stroke-width", "2");

    // Modification of custom tooltip code provided by Malcolm Maclean, "D3 Tips and Tricks" 
    // http://www.d3noob.org/2013/01/adding-tooltips-to-d3js-graph.html

});
```

Having this (shown below) in place of the .style("fill", function(d)....  works perfectly fine.

```
    .style("fill", "rgb(217,91,67)")
```

The above code is based on http://blockbuilder.org/anonymous/0e1213b567bcfc74376cc0e9a7238c1b, and the colorscale function is based on http://bl.ocks.org/nbremer/a43dbd5690ccd5ac4c6cc392415140e7.

Comment: When I made that blockbuilder you linked in your question, I was only showing you how to plot two circles in the same position. There is no `temp` property in the objects of that data array.

Comment: Yeah, I added the temp later. It's working now though, so no worries. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, your issue must be coming from your data :

```
.style("fill", function(d) {
    return colorScale(d.temp);
})
```

`d.temp` must be `undefined`

I did a fiddle as an example https://jsfiddle.net/ddspczr1/